# Approximating sum of entries of $\exp(A-B)$ for diagonal $A$ and rank-$1$ $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, matrix-exponential

I have non-negative $d\times d$ matrices $A$, $B$ and need a tractable way to compute the sum of all entries of $\exp(-t(A-B))$ where $A$ is diagonal and $B$ symmetric rank-$1$. IE

$$f(t)=\langle\exp(-t(A-B))\rangle$$

Where $t>0$ and $\langle M\rangle$ represents sum  of all entries of $M$.

**What expansion would be useful to estimate $f(t)$?**

I know that norms of $A$, $B$ and $A-B$ are less than one, $A-B$ is positive semi-definite and norm of $B$ is relatively small compared to norm of $A$.

I can only afford to perform $c\times d$ operations for small values of $c$.
Golden-Thompson [inequality](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/the-golden-thompson-inequality/) gives efficient to compute and tight bound for $\operatorname{Tr}$, but similar factoring is loose for $\langle\cdot\rangle$. Computing $f(t)$ would extend Velikanov's [approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11124) for computing SGD error after $t$ steps to small values of $t$.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-bounding-rank1.nb)

Comment: For what range of $t$?

Comment: For values $0<t<d^2$

Comment: Hmmm... $e^{d^2}$ is quite large. What error size (absolute or relative) will you agree to tolerate?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the sign of $t$, fixed. Setting $B$ to $0$ gives me a cheap lower bound that's off by a factor of $2$ from on realistic data. I'm looking for 1) a way to add some terms to shrink this gap 2) also obtain an upper bound on $f(t)$

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about "cheap lower bound" because $A>C$ does not imply $e^{-A}<e^{-C}$ in general. I'm curious if you can give me an example of "realistic data" to try a couple of ideas on because your notebook is a bit hard for me to decipher.

Comment: Cleaned-up further [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-DPR1-approx.nb). `generateDiagRank1` gives realistic diagonal and rank1 matrices, then example shows how to compare against data in $d=100$

Comment: OK, it makes it crystal clear what the goal is and what to compare, but leaves it completely unclear (to me) what is generated. Does generateDiagRank1[d] just output a random vector of length $d$ with independent entries uniformly distributed in some interval (if so, which one?) or it does something else?

Comment: $A-B=\operatorname{diag}(a)-b b^T$, where `{a,b}=generateDiagRank1(100)` $a=2h(1-h)$ and $b=h$ for $h$ representing empirically observed discrete probability distribution over $d$ outcomes

Comment: if it's feasible, why not conjugate by the square root of $A$, to reduce to the case $A=I$ ?

Comment: Yes, conjugating by square root of $A$ can be done since its cheap. But not sure if that makes the problem easier

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Conjugation means $A^{-1/2}(A-B)A^{1/2}$, not $A^{-1/2}(A-B)A^{-1/2}$, which is useless. The case $A=I$ is trivial because everything commutes, but you cannot reduce to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Asymptote code seems to work perfectly and for any $t$ in your range the estimate uses $Cd$ operations and is a guaranteed upper bound though I am not sure whether $C$ is small enough for you (I hope it is).

If you try to run it online on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ , the final pause() command should be removed. The output gives the value of $t$ (I run it over powers of 2 to make the comparison quick), the truth and the quick upper bound after it. All explanations tomorrow.

```
int d=300;

srand(seconds());

real p=0.6+2*unitrand();
real[] h,A;
real[][] C;

for(int k=0;k<d;++k) h[k]=exp(-p*log(k+1))*(1+2*unitrand());
h=reverse(sort(h));
real a=1/(2*max(h)+sum(h));

for(int k=0;k<d;++k) 
{
C[k]=new real[];
for(int l=0;l<d;++l) {C[k][l]=a^2*h[k]*h[l];}
real u=a*h[k];
A[k]=2*(u-u^2); C[k][k]+=1-2*(u-u^2);
}


real S(real[][] A)
{
real s=0; for(int k=0;k<d;++k) for(int l=0;l<d;++l) s+=A[k][l]; 
return s;
}

real[][] U=copy(C);

for(int kk=0;kk<19;++kk)
{
int t=2^kk;
write(t);

real la=A[d-1]-a^2*h[d-1]^2;
for(int p=0;p<4;++p)
{
real s=-1,ss=0;
for(int k=0;k<d;++k) {s+=a^2*h[k]^2/(A[k]-la); ss+=a^2*h[k]^2/(A[k]-la)^2;}
la-=s/ss;
}

pair r1=(-3.45888846213541,1.77794875224373), r2=(-0.541111537864589,5.00955180872487),
d1=(0.0960769769474388,0.281952388994648), d2=(-0.762743643614106,-0.350175117369014);


write(S(U));
real s=0; pair ss=(0,0),sss=(0,0); 

pair r=-1/r1;
for(int k=0;k<d;++k) {ss+=a*h[k]/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la)); sss+=(a*h[k])^2/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la));}
pair al=ss/(1-t*r*sss);
pair[] Q;
for(int k=0;k<d;++k) {Q[k]=-(2/d1/r1)*((1+t*r*al*a*h[k])/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la)));}


r=-1/r2;
ss=(0,0); sss=(0,0);
for(int k=0;k<d;++k) {ss+=a*h[k]/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la)); sss+=(a*h[k])^2/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la));}
pair al=ss/(1-t*r*sss);
for(int k=0;k<d;++k) {Q[k]-=(2/d2/r2)*((1+t*r*al*a*h[k])/(1+t*r*(A[k]-la)));}

for(int k=0;k<d;++k) s+=Q[k].x^2;
s*=(1-la)^t;

write(s);



write("************");
U*=U;
}


pause();
```

Now the explanations.

To the best of my understanding, you are aiming at finding $\langle(1-V)^t w,w\rangle$ with low *relative* error where $w$ is the vector of all $1$'s and $V=A-h\otimes h$ where $A=\text{diag}(a_j)$ and $h=(h_j)$ with $a_j,h_j>0$ ($j=1,\dots,d$).

The first observation is that we can factor out $(1-\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the least eigenvalue of $V$. It is the $\lambda$ that makes possible to have an equality in the positive definiteness Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\sum_j{a_j-\lambda}x_j^2\ge\left(\sum_j h_jx_j\right)^2$ which is the least root of the equation
$$
\sum_j\frac{h_j^2}{a_j-\lambda}=1\,.
$$
I'm finding it by Newton iterations (I used 4 in the above program but if you want to go really high in $t$, 6 would be better). Note that it is crucial to get the correct root, so one should start with the initial approximation $a_{j_0}-h_{j_0}^2$ where $a_{j_0}=\min_j a_j$. It is tempting to start with $0$, but that will often throw you in between $a_j$ and result in a wrong root, which will ruin everything.

Now we have $V=\lambda I+V'$ where $V'=A'-h\otimes h$, $A'=\text{diag\,}(a_j-\lambda)$ is a SPD matrix with the least eigenvalue $0$ and the corresponding unit eigenvector $e_0$ that has positive entries (proportional to $\frac{h_j}{a_j-\lambda}$). This
$$
(I-V)^t=(1-\lambda)^t(1-\tfrac 1{1-\lambda}V')^t\approx (1-\lambda)^t\exp(-\frac t{1-\lambda}V')
$$
and $\approx$ is an upper bound.

So, from now on, I'll remove the primes, denote $a_j-\lambda$ by $a_j$, $V'$ by $V$, and $\frac{t}{1-\lambda}$ by $t$ (I didn't divide $t$ by $(1-\lambda)$ in the code above because $\lambda$ was very small in your setting and you do not need it when finding $e^{-tV}$ but if you are after the discrete case, it helps a bit).

Theoretically, $\langle e^{-tV}w,w\rangle$ (BTW, I recommend computing it after this renormalization because the geometric progression $(1-\lambda)^t$ doesn't affect the relative error but can easily result in mantissa overflow) is just $\langle w,e_0\rangle^2+\sum_{j\ge 1}e^{-\gamma_j t}\langle w,e_j\rangle^2$ where $\gamma_j$ and $e_j$ are the remaining eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The idea is to replace it with $\langle F(tV)w,w\rangle$ where $F(t)\ge e^{-t}$ is a good approximation to $e^{-t}$ (we will discuss below how good we want it) and $\langle F(tV) w, w\rangle$ is reasonably quick to compute.

All I really know how to compute quickly is $w(z)=(I+zV)^{-1}w$. This calls for solving the system of equations
$$
w(z)_i (1+za_i)-z\langle w(z),h\rangle h_i=1\,.
$$
Let $\alpha=\langle w(z),h\rangle$. Then $w(z)_i=\frac{1+z\alpha h_i}{1+z a_i}$ and $\alpha$ can be found from
$$
\sum_i \frac{1+z\alpha h_i}{1+z a_i}h_i=\alpha\,,
$$
i.e., $\alpha=\frac{s_1}{1-zs_2}$ where $s_q=\sum_i \frac{h_i^q}{1+z a_i}$, $q=1,2$.

Thus we can afford *rational functions of not too high degree*. This is the key. We can now use $F(t)=P(t/2)^{-2}$ where $P$ is the partial sum of the Taylor series for $e^t$ (I used $P(t)=1+t+t^2/2+t^3/6+t^4/24$ in the above program because I was aiming at the range of hundreds (Asymptote will just run out of memory if you try to make a $d\times d$ matrix with $d=10^4$ and it is also about 100 times slower than C++, because it is an interpreter, not compiler; for $d\asymp 10^4$ I would rather recommend degree 8).

If $r_m$ are the (complex!) roots of $P$ (which have to be found once with high precision; I actually found the roots of $P(t/2)$ in the upper half-plane, those are the mysterious $r1$ and $r_2$ in the code) and $d_m=P'(r_m)$, then we have the representation
$$
\frac 1{P(t)}=\sum_m\frac {d_m}{t-r_m}=-\sum_m \frac 1{r_md_m}\frac 1{1+(-1/r_m)t}=-2\Re {\sum_m}' \frac 1{r_md_m}\frac 1{1+(-1/r_m)t}
$$
where ${\sum}'$ is taken over the roots in the upper half-plane (so you have to run the above computation just for 2 roots for degree 4, 4 roots for degree 8, etc.).

Thus we get
$$
P(tV/2)^{-1}w=-2\sum'_m \Re[(r_md_m)^{-1}w(-r_m^{-1})t/2]
$$
which is readily computable as above, and

$\langle P(tV/2)^{-2}w,w\rangle=\|P(tV/2)^{-1}w\|^2$ (one more summation of squares of entries).

Now it is time to discuss precision.

Since $\sum_{j\ge 0}\langle w,e_j\rangle^2=\|w\|^2=d$, we have
$$
\langle e^{-tV}w,w\rangle=\sum_{j\ge 1}\langle w,e_j\rangle^2\left[\tfrac {\langle w,e_0\rangle^2}{d-\langle w,e_0\rangle^2}+e^{-t\gamma_j}\right]
$$
and
$$
\langle F(t)w,w\rangle-\langle e^{-tV}w,w\rangle=
\sum_{j\ge 1}(F(t\gamma_j)-e^{-t\gamma_j})\langle w,e_j\rangle^2\,.
$$
Note that all terms are positive, so the relative error in the sum is at most the maximum of the relative errors in the individual terms. Note also that, since $e_0$ has positive entries, we have $\langle w,e_0\rangle\ge 1$. Thus we are interested in
$$
E=\max_{t>0}\frac{F(t)-e^{-t}}{\frac 1{d-1}+e^{-t}}=
max_{t>0}\frac{P(t/2)^{-2}-e^{-t}}{\frac 1{d-1}+e^{-t}}\,.
$$
This can be investigated theoretically, but I'll just make a small table (the first number is the degree of the polynomial and the second is $d$) so that you can see that for $n=4, d=100$ I have only 10% error *in the worst case scenario* (your data can never go that high) while for $d=10^4$, with $n=4$ I can theoretically go 150% above the truth while $n=8$ gives you guaranteed 5% precision at the expense of 2 extra roots. If you can afford $n=14$, you can go to ten millions range and declare your computations "precise".

*Edit:* The $\lambda$-story.

The estimate $E=E(d,n)$ for the relative error above is *uniform* in all $t>0$, but it is based of the assumption that the lowest eigenvalue $\gamma_0$ is exactly $0$, so not only the term $\langle w,e_0\rangle^2e^{-\gamma_0 t}$ is evaluated exactly by $\langle w,e_0\rangle^2 F(t)$, but it also stays fixed independently of $t>0$. The relative error bound is based *not* on the idea that $F(t)$ approximates $e^{-t}$ with small relative error on the whole semi-axis (that is impossible and you have a blow-up beyond $t=40$ or so for $n=16$) but on the idea that both $F(t)$ and $e^{-t}$ become negligibly small compared to $\frac 1{d-1}$ when the relative error between them becomes large.

In actual computation, you'll not be able to keep $\gamma_0$ exactly at $0$ (the computation of $\lambda$ has some error), so it is important to understand what happens if it is small. The answer is that as long as $|\gamma_0|t<0.01$, say, nothing changes in the bounds; just $1$ gets replaced by $0.99$ in the formula for $E$. However, if this product is large, the whole thing falls apart dramatically because you accumulate a huge relative error in the term that was presumed to be evaluated exactly and the numerator in $\frac 1{d-1}$ will also become $e^{-\gamma_0 t}$. So, you are theoretically guaranteed to have the relative error as claimed *only* if you use the $\lambda I$ reduction *and* compute $\lambda$ with the error at most $0.01 t^{-1}$. Otherwise you'll be outputting junk for large $t$. On the other hand, the theoretical guarantee (once you just check that its *assumptions* hold) is a sure one, so you do not need to check that its *conclusion* holds directly.

*Moral*: make sure that the error in $\lambda$ is much smaller than $1/t$ and you will not need to check anything else after that, provided that there is no stupid error in the code, which would reveal itself on small data.

```
2       10      0.17245166347402
2       100     0.961455640371778
2       1000    4.28015125191342
2       10000   19.7816887991447
2       100000  101.301563701775
2       1000000 570.64054529331
2       10000000        3464.50750307103
*********
4       10      0.0162756483432251
4       100     0.106015462775259
4       1000    0.429607071204345
4       10000   1.4053481903916
4       100000  4.41442731700713
4       1000000 14.7171384159884
4       10000000        54.2101332254995
*********
6       10      0.00166712645387837
6       100     0.0139026251293181
6       1000    0.0705786452201884
6       10000   0.2484898912299
6       100000  0.708166083384971
6       1000000 1.85420759122078
6       10000000        4.87739303482548
*********
8       10      0.00016984164765101
8       100     0.00166787956056493
8       1000    0.0110935381765316
8       10000   0.0492442082940087
8       100000  0.159219723419999
8       1000000 0.420853472933991
8       10000000        1.00146598253247
*********
10      10      1.73531792069359e-05
10      100     0.000183806352715792
10      1000    0.00151002712819166
10      10000   0.00873278982007405
10      100000  0.0352404205756958
10      1000000 0.107570103457829
10      10000000        0.271655462239004
*********
12      10      1.78880885047298e-06
12      100     1.94620128830683e-05
12      1000    0.000180991851874676
12      10000   0.00131944915308362
12      100000  0.00681706198345839
12      1000000 0.0256053500194781
12      10000000        0.0750096474609068
*********
14      10      1.86072838564969e-07
14      100     2.04069133751507e-06
14      1000    2.00507453637578e-05
14      10000   0.000172432808234548
14      100000  0.00112204219089126
14      1000000 0.0052891118636613
14      10000000        0.0187925172629428
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this work, I'll dive deeper into this on Monday. The concrete $h$ I'll try to evaluate it on is for $h=1^{-p},2^{-p},\ldots,d^{-p}$ with $p=1.1$ and $d=10000$. Looking forward to your explanation!

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Here is the underlying "mini-theory". I hope it gives you enough speed in your computations. Also make sure that you have enough precision: I wouldn't dare to raise a number to the power $d^2=10^8$ with just regular double type. Let me know how it works out and feel free to ask as many questions as you want :-)

Comment: still parsing through the details, but I can run the code and it's faster than I thought was possible. BTW, there's a [simple expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653810/computing-operatornametr-textduuk-using-generating-functions#mjx-eqn-Atilde_solution) for resolvent of $V$ in terms of resolvent of $A$ and resolvent of $h\otimes h$, I wonder if that could be useful here

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Well, it is pretty much equivalent to my formulas, so I don't think you'll get away with one summation before finding the entries of $w(z)$. Also, if we take into account that addressing the element of an array is like 8 multiplication (or, at least, that is how it was when I learned programming), I guess that won't help anyway. If the code is "faster than you thought possible", try to increase the degree of $P(t)$ a bit. Note that it doesn't use the special structure of the data except the positivity of the entries of $h$. What is the largest $d$ you really want to handle?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Also there are still a few stupid misprints like $F(w)$ instead of the correct $F(t)$, but I do not want to bump the thread to the front page again now, so I hope they are not too confusing :-)

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you are using $\alpha$ and $s_q$ It seems to be the only place that uses $h_i$, but I don't immediately see the connection to $P$. All other mentions of $P$ and $F$ in your description use eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $V$, but those are not efficiently computable, so trying to figure out what $s_q$ are for

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov $\alpha$ and $s_q$ are not related to $P$, but to just finding $w(z)=(I+zV)^{-1}w$ for *a fixed* $z$). $P$ and $F$ appear later and *use* this computation to find $w(-r_j^{-1}t/2)$ (another idiotic misprint: $t/2$ escaped from the argument of $w$) in the formula for $P(tV/2)^{-1}w$.

Comment: I see thanks. I'm trying to understand how you are connecting resolvent to matrix exponential. I'm guessing it's the equation right after "Thus we get"....where does this equation come from?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It comes straight from the previous displayed formula: once we have an identity for the rational functions, we can apply it to the operators (rational calculus is always available with one over becoming the inverse of the corresponding operator). Note again that there is a misprint on the RHS (see my comment above)

Comment: Haven't seen this rational calculus trick before, looking for some intro materials

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Have you seen the *polynomial* operator calculus? If yes, just multiply by the common denominator. Or, for self-adjoint operators, just diagonalize and check everything for the diagonal case.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov There are some introductory lectures online like https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~kirillov/MATH548-F07/Lect1.pdf which may help though the best way to understand it is just to try to check the corresponding statements yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks for the notes, starting to understand now. So your representation rewrites polynomial in terms of terms that look like resolvents. Does this trick have a name? I don't understand why you only need roots in top half plane

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov *one over* the polynomial. The bottom half-plane roots are complex conjugate, so if $A$ is the sum over the top half plane roots, then the sum over the bottom half plane roots is $\bar A$, and instead of honestly computing it again and writing the full sum as $A+\bar A$, you can just take twice the real part, which reduces the running time twice. Note that I used even $n$, so there is no (negative) root on the real line (otherwise it would have to be treated separately). The trick is just partial fraction decomposition. Recall those boring rational function integration drills.

Comment: Ok I understand it enough now to reimplement from scratch.and do some evals, pretty neat trick. I understand that you are doing something in the spirit of [Heaviside](https://planetmath.org/heavisideformula) formula - constructing a cheap rational expression to write nverse Laplace transform in terms of few samples. I'm curious, is there an analogous  sampling interpolation trick for the forward Laplace?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Great. Just be careful with precision issues! And what exactly do you mean by "an analogous trick of the forward Laplace?" (I.e., what should it accomplish?). Also, have you understood the theoretical relative error estimates I provided?

Comment: For the forward I mean suppose we are able to evaluate exp(x) cheaply , but need (1+x)^{-1}. For the precision, you are measuring it for scalar arguments and saying it transfers to generalized arguments, right?

Comment: "you are measuring it for scalar arguments and saying it transfers to generalized arguments" Not sure what exactly you mean by that, but if it is "the relative error of the sum of positive terms does not exceed the maximum of the relative errors of individual terms", then yes. The formula for $E$ gives you the worst case scenario (i.e., if the truth is $T$, you computed estimate will be between $T$ and $(1+E)T$), so I would write a program that allows you to choose the degree $n$ of the polynomial (that will require precomputing and storing several sets of complex roots and derivatives).

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Let me know how your implementation worked. I'd like to add a few more final comments about this problem, but I'd rather not bother you with them until you finish the implementation and test it to your satisfaction or otherwise :-)

Comment: Didn't forget about it, a naive port worked and the underlying math is really amazing so catching up more on background. Plan to clean up and do some evals tomorrow. This method appears to extend beyond DPR1 matrices, any matrix with cheap to compute resolvent appears to benefit from this trick!

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov OK, keep me updated (especially if you face some unexpected issues or inexplicable aberrations: the technique is theoretically sound but we both know that implementing something in a stable and reliable way on a real machine has its own challenges :lol:)

Comment: So the error looks pretty good, eval [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-nexp-approx-eval.nb). One thing I realized when looking at [concrete formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282625/217) for sum of entries of (1+z A)^{-1} is that it has the form of Heaviside [formula](https://planetmath.org/heavisideformula) when $A$ is diagonal + rank1, so a more direct method for exp(-z A) appears possible

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Erm... What are you testing? $d=2$ with $t\in[0,100]$? That is not what you need 8 roots for! Also, I do not see the preliminary reduction by $\lambda I$, which is essential if you want small relative error in the whole range of t for large d. You should test $d$ up to $10^8$ and $t$ running up to $d^2$ over powers of 2, if you want to see what is really possible. I'm totally confused about what you are reporting. Can you enlighten me what you are trying to do, really?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Also, notice that I'm not trying to approximate $e^{-tV}$ but $e^{-tV/2}$. Yes, it is possible to write the answer as $(P^{-1}(V)w,w)$ and then you'll just need to sum the entries instead of their squares, but that would require a higher degree of the polynomial to get the decent precision and I was trying to keep it as low as feasible. Want to discuss it all on Skype/Zoom in person?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Here are the guaranteed relative errors that you should have if you implement the code correctly for n=16 (8 roots) in the format $(d,E)$: $(10^1, 2\cdot 10^{-8}),(10^2, 2.2\cdot 10^{-7}), (10^3, 2.2*10^{-6} ), (10^4, 2.1\cdot 10^{-5} ), (10^5, 1.6*10^{-4}), (10^6, 10^{-4} ), (10^7, 0.005), (10^8, 0.014 ), (10^9, 0.038)$. That should be true for all $t>0$ for which $t$ times the error you've made in the approximation of $\lambda$ is negligible. (so if you want it to be correct for $t=10^{18}$, make sure that you $\lambda$ is correct up to $10^{-25}$, say.

Comment: No, I was evaluating with d=100 because it takes O(d^3) to compare relative error against ground truth (explicit computation of matrix exponential). For d=10^8 I don't have a way to see what the error is, so I'll assume it's small. I see that your method is very similar to Section 3 of [Gallopoulos](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/CSRD_90_969.pdf) with the difference that they use Chebychev approximation. They give coefficients in Table 5 but seems like overkill, this solution appears already to have high enough accuracy, thanks!

Comment: "for d=10^8 I don't have a way to see what the error is, so I'll assume it's small." @YaroslavBulatov You *do have a way*, if you know where to look, and that is where $\lambda$ and its precision comes into play. We are not in church: there is no need to accept anything on faith. I'll explain it later today. But first, you should incorporate the computation of $\lambda$ and reduction by $\lambda I$ into your code. Without it, you may be fine for $d,t=100$, but will be *way off* for $d=10^8, t=10^{16}$.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Actually, you'll be way off even with $d=100, t=10^{16}$, which you can compute directly. Just run your code as it is with that $d$ increasing $t$ along powers of 2 (squaring a 100 by 100 matrix is a fast enough operation). You'll see something interesting :-)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I added a few words to the answer to explain why the computation of $\lambda$ is absolutely indispensable if you want the code to work correctly, what exactly you should verify so that you would *know* what happens for large $t$ and $d$, not just *assume* it, and why your assumptions about the error in your code without $\lambda$ were completely unjustified. As usual, feel free to ask questions, if anything is unclear :-)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code + approximation pointers, it was quite useful for validating hypotheses and I learned a lot. I actually don't need any higher accuracy -- the reason is that matrices $A$,$B$ are not known and have to be estimated from data, sometimes all you know is that eigenvalues follow power-law decay with approximately known constant $p$. The underlying problem behind this question is summarized [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-rank1-recurrence.nb). I can solve the "diag" case with explicit formula, but not "diag+rank1" case

Comment: So the solution you provided above solves the problem in [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-rank1-recurrence.nb) accurately in $O(d)$ time which works great medium problems. For the largest problems $d$ can be trillions, so I'd need an approximate solution it in $O(1)$ time, if you have ideas how to do the larger scale version, I'll be happy to post this as a separate question

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov " if you have ideas how to do the larger scale version, I'll be happy to post this as a separate question" Sure, but since you are looking for something better than $O(d)$, you'll have to explain clearly what assumptions about the data you are making since in this case one cannot even read the data entirely

Comment: BTW, I've been wrapping my head around this method, and it [appears](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4681797/998) this method comes out as special case of the residue theorem. Depending on the contour you choose, you will get either this method, or the standard method based on eigenvalue decomposition

Comment: btw, I gave background on the underlying problem and referenced your implementation [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)