# Upper bounds on Inverse Laplace transform of a rational function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform

I need the inverse Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}^{-1}$ or a nice upper bound on $\mathscr{L}^{-1}$ for the following function:
$$f(y)=\frac{\left(\sum_i \frac{u_i}{y-a_i}\right)^2}{1-\sum_i u_i \frac{u_i}{y-a_i}}$$

Any advice?

---

- This comes out of rank-1 correction to matrix exponential of diagonal matrix.
- $\mathscr{L}^{-1}f=\langle\exp(t (A + B)) - \exp(t A), \mathbf{1}\rangle$ where $\langle M, \mathbf{1}\rangle=\sum_{ij}M_{ij}$, $A$ diagonal, $B=uu'$ is rank-1
- Fedya gave a nice [numeric algorithm](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443030/7655) to compute this, now I need higher-level understanding such as:
- if $u_i=i^{-1.12}$, and $a_i=-2u_i(1-u_i)$, how fast does $\mathscr{L}^{-1}f$ decay? Reason for $-1.12$ is Figure 9 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11124).
- also [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665988/inverse-laplace-transform-rank1-correction-of-matrix-exponential) on math.SE a few days ago. A user on that forum [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665988/inverse-laplace-transform-rank1-correction-of-matrix-exponential#comment9863867_4665988) that roots of $f(y)$ appear to be real

[image]
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mathoverflow-laplace-inverse.nb)

Comment: How about we use the inverse-LT contour formula and residue since it seems that you have exact information on the location of the poles?

Comment: I can get explicit formula for specific value of $a$ by plugging it into Mathematica. I'm rather looking for nice bounds, ie, $g(t)<t^{-0.25}$ when $u_i=i^{-1.12}$ and $a_i=-2u_i(1-u_i)$

Comment: the contour-formula should give expressions for general $a$ too. From the residue-expressions the bounds might be easy to get.